# test iterator value in struts 2

Tags: if-statement, struts2

I want to select option in drop down on condition.

```
 <s:set var="defaultState" value="customerBean.state"/>
                                        <select onchange="reflect(this);"  name="customerBean.state" class="form-control"  id="state">
                                            <option>Select</option>
                                            <s:iterator value="stateList" var="statevalue">

                                                <s:if test="%{#defaultState.equalsIgnoreCase(stateValue)}">  
                                                    <option id="stateVal" selected="selected"><s:property value="statevalue"/></option>

                                                </s:if>  
                                                <s:else>  
                                                    <option id="stateVal"><s:property value="statevalue"/></option>
                                                </s:else> 
                                            </s:iterator>
                                        </select>
```

this does not work. But if I put

`<s:if test="%{#defaultState.equalsIgnoreCase('Alabama')}">`

this works.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that it is not a simple typo? In your code you are using `stateValue` and `statevalue`.

Beside that is `stateList` a simple list or is it a list of beans? For the second option you have to use something like `stateValue.value`.

Another option: Because it is an OGNL-Expression you could try also `#statevalue`. But I'm never sure when to use with `#` and when without.

Another option: use the struts tag [s:select](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) and to preselect the option use the `value` attribute.

Comment: thanks for reply @beendr. I already used s:select and it worked. stateList  is simple ArrayList.